# java sql update statement with user input

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

I have a problem updating my table from java.

i need to check colmunID(from my table PRODUCTS) = int id(given by user input) and change thats product price in table to one given by user.

PROBLEM:

```
 static void x(int Userid, int Userprice) {
 ..........................................
   String sql = "UPDATE  Product set Price = Userprice where ID=Userid; ";
....}
```

I get error that i don't have column Userprice or Userid in my database. I don't know how to write this to check int User id which is given as argument in this method and not column in my database table which does not exists.

Comment: are you using JDBC? how dont you know what column you have in your database...do a 'desc product;' in your database env

Comment: you need to escape the values you are inputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have both the columns with `Integer` datatype in DB,

```
String sql = "UPDATE  Product set Price="+Userprice+" where ID="+Userid;
```

You are not passing the actual values to it and the extra ';' is not required. Also, I suggest you to prefer prepared statements, rather than above approach

Answer (score 1):

While you definitely in production code want to use prepared statements to prevent sql injection, an easy fix would be the below.

```
String sql = String.format("UPDATE  Product set Price = %d where ID=%d ",Userprice,Userid);
```

String wont evaluate variables in itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the table for Userid does not exist in your database, you will not be able to use this in your SQL query.  There are two options for you:
1. Pass the Userid and Userprice as a variables to the SQL query

```
    String sql = "UPDATE  Product set Price = " + Userprice + "where ID=" + Userid+ "; "
```

Or
2. Create the table in the database and join on that

```
    String sql = "Update A Set A.Price = b.Userprice FROM Product as A INNER JOIN User as b on A.Userid = b.ID;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
Connection con = null;
try {
con = getConnection();
String sql = "UPDATE  Product set Price = ? where ID= ? ";          
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);         
            ps.setString(1, Userprice); 
            ps.setString(2, Userid); 
            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0) { 
                System.out.println("Product Updated"); 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error Occured");
            }
```

I think this is something you are looking for... The query should not contain ';' in the String for your code